# Why does my car get stuck when I accelerate and turn at the same time?

Tags: noise, hyundai, acceleration, elantra

Whenever I hit the gas pedal and make a left turn the vehicle will not move forward. It gets stuck and makes a strange noise. I literally have to let off the gas before turning and coast. This also happens randomly when accelerating down a highway without any turns. To get the car to move again I have to let off the gas and re-apply the pressure gradually in hopes it'll catch. However, the left turn specifically triggers this strange effect on command.

Any thoughts?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission/mileage of the car in question?

Comment: Thank you! It is a 2012 Hyundai Elantra. I am quite unsure about the engine, but I do believe the transmission is automatic (from what I've read), and the car has about 120,000 miles on it

Comment: Is your gear shifter with  p r n d or 1 2 3 4 5 r?

Comment: The health of your CV joints may be in question

Comment: Yes, AsenM, our gear shifter is p r n d. We are currently unable to shift into "manual mode" though. I am not sure if that has anything to do with anything but figured it may be helpful for others to know. Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: Hi, SteveRacer. My husband and I just tested it out and compared the noise to that of youtube videos with cars that have bad CV joints and its making a much different noise. Instead of a clicking, our car sounds kind of like its gurgling metal. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Gurgling metal leaves two issue possibilities.

1. Theres an intake leak, find it by listening for rpm change and spraying brake cleaner around the intake. They specifically rip around the plastic ribbing. This explains the power loss when accelerating. It would make a sound called "pinging" under heavy throttle.
2. Your transmission fluid is very low, this explains the power loss when you go specifically through a left turn. Check it after driving thru all the gears, while the car is on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like either a transmission problem or a seized CV joint on the front wheel drive axle.

Damaged CV joints tend to make a clunking sound when under load, for instance while the car is making a turn under acceleration. They rarely fail suddenly, so for this to be the case the clunking sound (but not the seizing) should have been present for a while prior to your 'getting stuck' problems.